# Translate text-variable, then place it in tkinter label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, translate

I am working on a very basic translation app using python. Essentially it takes whatever you input into a entry box, replaces some letters (Ex. Turns "a" into "u") and then displays it as a label. Unfortunately the word that you input never gets translated, it just stays as it is. No errors appear in the console. Here's the bit of the code that should do this:

```
eword = StringVar()
Entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=eword, width=30, bg="lightgrey").place(x=250, y=155)

def translate(eword):
    translation = ""
    for letter in eword:
        if letter in "a":
            translation = translation + "e"
        elif letter in "m":
            translation = translation + "n"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation



def doit():
    text = eword.get()
    label3 = Label(root, text=text, font=("Arial", 20), bg="white").place(x=195, y=300)
    return
```

I am an absolute beginner in python so please explain things simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cahnged the layout a bit and added necessary code for it to run.

StringVar is not an ordinary string. To read its value you need to use the method `get()`, to write to it you use `set()`.

When you create the entry: `Entry1 = Entry(root, ...).place(x=250, y=155)` the variable `Entry1` will get the value `None`, because that is what `place()` returns. I have separated the creation of the entry from the placing on the window. Also, I'm using `pack()` instead of `place()`.

I have added a button to initiate the translation as I don't find any mechanism in your code. The button calls the function `translate()` when pressed.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()                 # Application main window
root.geometry('300x200')    # Setting a size

eword = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=eword, width=30)
entry1.pack(pady=20)    # Pack entry after creation 

def translate():
    original = eword.get()  # Read contents of eword
    translation = ""
    for letter in original:
        if letter in "a":
            translation = translation + "e"
        elif letter in "m":
            translation = translation + "n"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    new_text.set(translation)  # Write translation to label info

action = Button(root, text='Translate', command=translate)
action.pack()   # Pack button after creation 

new_text = StringVar()
info = Label(root, textvariable=new_text)
info.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of looping through the string you could use `replace()`:

```
original.replace('a', 'e')
original.replace('m', 'n')
```

You might want to research the string function `translate()` as well :)

Comment: Awesome, I had a button already, just didn't want to post my whole code.

Comment: Also, how would I later display that on the GUI, do I just add a Label at the end on the translate function?

Comment: I updated my answer with a label. I'm assigning the translation to the label at the end of the function via a `StringVar()` associated with the label.